# Kill TIME_WAIT sockets immediately?

Tags: linux, tcp, socket

Is there anyway to kill those `TIME_WAIT` sockets immediately ? e.g output of netstat:

```
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8080          127.0.0.1:41500         TIME_WAIT   -                   
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8080          127.0.0.1:41501         TIME_WAIT   -
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Need not, they're there by reason — «… [The purpose of TIME-WAIT is](http://www.isi.edu/touch/pubs/infocomm99/infocomm99-web/) to prevent delayed packets from one connection being accepted by a later connection …»

Linux also has [net.ipv4.tcp_tw_recycle](http://git.kernel.org/?p=linux/kernel/git/stable/linux-stable.git;a=blob;f=Documentation/networking/ip-sysctl.txt;h=1619a8c8087341477621388701fec82ca832b70b;hb=HEAD#l472) and net.ipv4.tcp_tw_reuse which can be helpful. Another tool to mention is [linux-tcp-drop](https://github.com/arut/linux-tcp-drop)

Comment: There is also a small utility called cutter to terminate TCP connections. It does not require building a kernel module. Included in some linux distributions. I've also seen a perl script to do the same but can't find it now.

Comment: @akostadinov, those connections are already terminated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use killcx(http://killcx.sourceforge.net/) perl command, it will do the job