# How to gracefully stop process that runs a tcp server on specific port?

Tags: systemd, tcp, socket, port

I have a systemd service unit that starts a tcp server on a specific port on the host machine.

but on restart the port cotinue to run and if I restart the service I get an error address already in use.

on digging more I found the port of tcp server is still open because service failed to start but if we stop the service the open tcp port closes.

Comment: After an ungraceful shutdown, a tcp socket can remain in the in-use state for typically 2 minutes. can this be your problem?

Comment: It it is, then `netstat` will show that the socket state is `TIME-WAIT`. Is it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Kill TIME\_WAIT sockets immediately?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/40580/kill-time-wait-sockets-immediately)

Comment: That's a very old thread with actually very little information @AndyDalton.

Comment: The linked thread does not help me.

Comment: and `netstat` result only in following data `Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name` cannot spot `TIME_WAIT` in any column row

Comment: I have updated my opening post, the TCP server's open port does not closes if the service fails.

Comment: That suggests that the service is actually still running and has the port in use. Even if it failed to start completely. It suggests that your restart-service command does not stop a previous instance.

Comment: well, sorry for my vague knowledge about systemd service , I disabled the service but still I am seeing status failed when used `systemctl --user status photon_uploader` instead of status inactive.

Comment: We really need more information. Such as your actual restart-command, netstat output, and/or /proc information. From an error that the address is in use, we can only conclude that maybe that is just what it is, the address is in use by a running process.

Comment: I have put the whole code of `TCPServer` and systemd unit here https://stackoverflow.com/q/59013014/3311276 since it fits different context, however now I have killed the process .

Comment: result of `netstat` `tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:7138          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1341/systemd  `

Comment: It confirms that the process is indeed still running, and that it still has the tcp port open.

Comment: if process is still running does that mean systemd service failed byt the python process is running in the background  ? so if that is the case on systemd failure it should kill the process , but I do not know how to achieve it ? Also if the systemd is failing that means systemd service is not implemented correctly